# How to predict traffic speeds on a National US Holiday

Tags: statistics

I have access to archives of the speeds on certain roads in the US, going back to 2014. What I want to do is form a prediction of what traffic conditions will be like on July 4th this year.

My initial thoughts were to calculate a percentage difference for the speed on road segments on the days around July 4th, against the average conditions on the road at that time, for each year. Then I would extrapolate for 2017. However a large flaw in this plan is that July 4th falls on a different day of the week each year. This year it will fall on a Tuesday, and the last time it fell on a Tuesday was 2006. Obviously, day of the week will have a drastic impact on traffic, however there are probably more complex interactions. If the holiday fell on a Wednesday people might use July 4th for day trips, while if it fell on a Friday people would take the three day weekend and travel further afield.

My assumptions are that people are likely to take the Monday off of work, leave on the Friday and come back on the Tuesday. In this way I can model the holiday as a three day weekend, with the Monday being similar conditions to Sunday. Does this approach work the best given the limited data to work with, or is there a better model I could be using for predicting traffic conditions?

Comment: I think that you would need much more data to make a good estimate.  As you say, the day of the week.  Far enough back to get all of the days would be minimum and I would like to see them each twice or more.  I don't know the US rules, if July 4 is a Saturday or Sunday, do you get a substitute?  That might slightly reduce the data needed but there still could be a difference between a holiday on Monday July 4 and Monday July 5 or 6.

Comment: At this point I'm resigned to building the best bad estimate. Traffic can be dramatically influenced by unforeseeable things like car crashes as well.

Comment: Of course, there are many possible unforeseen circumstances.  As well as crashes, a very obvious possible factor is the weather.  However, you may be able to reasonably admit those as unknown.  I think that you would still need lots more data to make any sort of useful estimate.  I was at a forecasting seminar once.  The presenter said: you are lucky or wrong and you are not often lucky.

Comment: I think this is a project better pursued via algorithm than model. Many predictor variables would not be linear and relationships would change over time. A few obvious relevant variables (in addition to year and day of the week for 7/4) are changes in gas prices, auto registrations in the region, changes in number of lanes of traffic, weather, and so on. Data during WWII when there was strict gas rationing should be omitted. Maybe earlier data also because of many changes in uses of autos over time. // Overall, maybe better advice on specifics at our 'crossvalidated' site.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to admit I'm not sure what the difference is between a model and an algorithm in this case.